# requested page give 404 in server but works perfect in localhost codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am programming a website using codeiginter i have an items in home page when click on it  it's open item details in new page 
the details page work perfect in localhost but when i upload the site the page doesn't work it give me error 404
this is url to test

server url (It's URL doesn't work) :

```
 http://flux-electric.com/product_detials/view_product/9
```

localhost url (It's URL work) :

```
localhost/new_site/product_detials/view_product/9
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution the mistake the first letter of Controller was small i change it to capital and it works perfect